# How control hover on select2 tagbox container

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-select2

The border of my select2 container turns red when I hover over it.  I would like to be able to turn this feature on and off using jquery.  I've searched all morning for a way to do this but I've now paralysed my brain! Is it even possible?
Any help much appreciated.  Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b5m7rnpw/

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js

<select id="dropList" style="width:300px" multiple="multiple">
<option value="Planet">Planet</option>
<option value="Earth">Earth</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<button  id='OnOffhover' class='buttonstyle' type="button">Click to turn red hover border On / Off</button>



$("#dropList").select2({ placeholder: "Select type", });  

$('#OnOffhover').on('click',function() {
    // some code
})




body {padding:30px;}

.buttonstyle{
width:260px;
height:20px;
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple:hover { 
border: 1px solid red;
background-color: white;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a class, for example:

```
.hover:hover {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

And then add/remove the class with jQuery, using [.addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [.removeClass()](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) or [.toggleClass()](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

As example:
http://jsfiddle.net/b5m7rnpw/1/

Comment: Very grateful to you @Jm.  It's obvious when you know how!

Comment: @Silverburch: glad I could help.